# Javascript spliting a string with multiple integer values with delimiter as "." retrns wrong values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript string and I want to split it using delimiter "." with exact value as integer.

```
<script>
var string = "6.100";
string.split(".");
console.log(string[2]); // Returns 1, I need 100 as output.
</script>
```

Comment: Works fine for me: `"6.100".split(".") === ["6", "100"];` - did you really mean "string[2]"? There are only two entries in the array, 0 and 1. - just noticed you are not storing the result of `string.split(`. It does not modify the string, it returns a new value, as in Ozil's answer.

Comment: Try this,
var value=string.split(".");
console.log(value[1]);

Answer (score 2):

```
var string = "6.100";
var newstring=string.split(".");
console.log(newstring[1]); // Returns 1, I need 100 as output.
```

Answer (score 0):

array start on index- 0, so

string.split(".") will be:

string[0] // is 6
string[1] // is 100

so use

> string[1]

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var string = "6.100";
    string = string.split("."); // Assign the array again after splitting
    console.log(string[1]); // Returns 100 as output.
</script>
```

Hope it helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform `split` on this string you will have `string[0]=6` and `string[1]=100`